# NAudio - How can I remove the last milliseconds (400) of audio when recording audio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm making a recording audio program using NAudio and I'd like to remove the last 400 milliseconds of a recording when it's done. Hopefully and possibly without reducing bitrate or audio quality. I'm also recording extremely high bitrate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
                using (var Reader = new AudioFileReader(InputFile)) //Read File
                {
                    var StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0); //Set Start Time

                    Reader.CurrentTime = StartTime;

                    var EndTime = Reader.TotalTime - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400); //Set EndTime Upto 400ms before End

                    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(OutputPath, Reader.Take(EndTime));
                }
```